# C++ Which function is faster? Repeated assignation or repeated creation

Tags: c++, performance, function, variables, static

I think the below image explains it pretty much, but the difference basically being a static variable which is assigned every call, or a normal variable which is created(?) every call.

[image: Which function is faster?]

Thanks for any insight you might have.

EDIT: I've added a quick program.  I don't know how pointless it is, but they execute in the same time.  I got a feeling it's not a good test.  I guess it's not worth worrying about.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#define ONE_BILLION 1000000000
#define HUNDRED_MILLION 100000000


long long functionStatic(int arg)
{
    static long long randNum;
    srand(time(NULL));
    randNum = rand() % 20;
    return arg + randNum;
}

long long functionLocal(int arg)
{
    long long randNum;
    srand(time(NULL));
    randNum = rand() % 20;
    return arg + randNum;
}


int main()
{
    long long timeStart;
    long long duration;
    long long randNum;
    long long accum = 0;

    timeStart = clock();


    for (int i = 0; i < HUNDRED_MILLION; i++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        randNum = rand() % 50;
        accum += functionStatic(randNum);
    }

    cout << "Time for static variable function: " << clock() - timeStart << " milliseconds" << endl << endl;
    timeStart = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < HUNDRED_MILLION; i++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        randNum = rand() % 50;
        accum += functionLocal(randNum);
    }

    cout << "Time for local variable function: " << clock() - timeStart << " milliseconds" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just realised the example isn't a great one, because you could just rewrite the function "return Someclass:number + Someclass::number2 + 2"

But, in principle, which would be faster of them two?  Thanks.

Comment: My guess would be the static assignment would be faster because you don't have to reallocate memory everytime but I don't it would be significant, and either way you'd have to make a test to figure it out.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Just paste the code.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was easier to read, because of the different colours.

Comment: Almost certainly the first one.

Comment: For `int` a local variable is usually faster because it can be placed on a register. A static must exist in global memory and may consume some memory even when the function is not called. I'm assuming `number` and `number2` are constants.

Comment: As usual for performance questions, the answer is to measure it and see.  However, based on my experience, as long as you have optimizations turned on, there won't be a difference.

Comment: No, number and number2 would be changing, so that the results of the return are unpredictable.  But my example is not a good one because of what I said in my first comment.

Comment: In regard to people saying to actually benchmark/test it, it turns out if I add the keyword static to a variable, the compiler refuses to optimise anything.  So I could test it in debug mode or with optimisations turned off.

Comment: Plus the second version is unsafe to call concurrently from multiple threads.

Comment: In that case you should definitely not make it static.

Comment: Do not put images in posts. It makes the code harder to read, almost impossible to copy to reproduce the problem on others' computers and not indexable/searchable. Paste the code here and press ctrl+K to format it

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714), [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: I've looked at those links, thanks for the advice.  Whenever I write code straight in it's usually all in black and white and I thought a screenshot from my compiler would be easier to read, because it distinguishes the data types and so on.  I won't do it again.

Answer (score 3):

Let's See what's happening in both the cases.

**Case 1:-** `int a` as a local variable.

In this case the compiler can do optimization i.e it can place it in a register or the cache. So if the function is being called many many times obviously this one will have a slight edge over the `static` variable.

**Case 2:-** making it `static int a`

In this case as soon as the variable is initialized it will be allocated a storage in the **static data area** of the program and be there till the program is exited.
The compiler also refuses to perform any optimization on this one, so every time the function is called `a` would be fetched from the main memory then modified and then again written to the main memory,this would translate to **more number of assembly instructions** than the first case.

**Final Verdict:-** The First case may be better than the second.But it may not be the case always because there are more factors that can affect the performance such as the Compiler,the CPU,the underlying hardware platform or the OS as mentioned by others.

Answer (score 3):

There's a point that hasn't really been covered yet, that I think is related to your question. In your example, you happened to use an int. Because you did (would have worked for any trivial type), the static initialization can be done in a particularly efficient way. However, creating a static variable in a function can be extremely expensive:

```
struct A {
  A(double y) : z(y) { }

  double z;
 };

A func(double x) {
  static A a(0);
  a.z += x;
  return a;
}
```

Compiles to (with -O2):

```
func(double):                               # @func(double)
    push    rax
    mov al, byte ptr [rip + guard variable for func(double)::a]
    test    al, al
    jne .LBB0_3
    mov edi, guard variable for func(double)::a
    movsd   qword ptr [rsp], xmm0   # 8-byte Spill
    call    __cxa_guard_acquire
    movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rsp]   # 8-byte Reload
    test    eax, eax
    je  .LBB0_3
    mov qword ptr [rip + func(double)::a], 0
    mov edi, guard variable for func(double)::a
    call    __cxa_guard_release
    movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rsp]   # 8-byte Reload
.LBB0_3:
    addsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rip + func(double)::a]
    movsd   qword ptr [rip + func(double)::a], xmm0
    pop rax
    ret
```

What's going on? Well, a static local like a must be initialized exactly once, the first time func is called. But how can you make sure that happens? You have to create an invisible boolean variable, initialize it to false, check it before initializing, only initialize if false, and then set it to true. And do all that in a thread safe way. With the previous example, we had a trivial type (int) with a constant initialization value. So the compiler just performs the initialization at compile time, and then generate code that omits the initialization.

Although your example was with an integer, the text of your question was general. Therefore, I feel the correct answer should really be: in general, try to steer clear of static locals if you care about performance.

Answer (score 2):

With g++ 4.9.2, built with -O2, there is a slight penalty for using the static, since it doesn't optimize away the store.

```
// static int a;
// a = 2;
// a += Someclass::number + Someclass::number2;
mov    0x0(%rip),%eax      # Get Someclass::number
add    0x0(%rip),%eax      # Add Someclass::number2
add    $0x2,%eax           # Add 2
mov    %eax,0x0(%rip)      # Store result in a
retq                       # return
```

The version where `a` isn't static has one less instruction:

```
// int a = 2;
// a += Someclass::number + Someclass::number2;
mov    0x0(%rip),%eax      # Get Someclass::number  
add    0x0(%rip),%eax      # Add Someclass::number2
add    $0x2,%eax           # Add 2
retq                       # Return
```

However, with clang 3.6.0, the result is the same either way:

```
// static int a;
// a = 2;
// a += Someclass::number + Someclass::number2;
mov    0x0(%rip),%eax    
mov    0x0(%rip),%ecx    
lea    0x2(%rax,%rcx,1),%eax
retq


// int a = 2;
// a += Someclass::number + Someclass::number2;
mov    0x0(%rip),%eax    
mov    0x0(%rip),%ecx    
lea    0x2(%rax,%rcx,1),%eax
retq
```

Comment: I noticed that if I add the keyword static to a variable in a function, my compiler (Visual Studio 15) won't optimise anything, not even a silly loop like: 

 
for (i= 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
 
{
      1 + 1;
} 

Isn't it better performance testing with optimisation off to actually see what code is faster?  Because optimisation sometimes throws code out completely.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice: It would only be better to test performance with optimizations turned off if you are going to be delivering your application with optimizations turned off, which I don't recommend.

Answer (score 1):

No real answer is possible other than "it depends".

Your question really belongs in the "premature optimisation" basket.   The fact you have not mentioned concepts like "testing" or "profiling" - and are instead worrying about performance of particular code constructs in isolation - supports that characterisation.

Using a static means a (one-off) creation of that static sometime before the first call of the function, and reassigning every time.   At run time, that means accessing and/or modifying the most recent value at that location in memory.    That can mean, depending on how frequently the function is called and how the CPU works, accessing processor cache, going back to RAM (which is slower than cache), or retrieving the data at that location from swap space (much slower than memory if swap space on a hard drive).    The performance therefore depends on the memory architecture of the host system, and is potentially somewhat variable.

Using an auto variable generally means allocating and initialising some area of stack space.   The performance of that, again, depends on memory architecture of the host system, but is unlikely to be as variable as with a static.

The compiler can also potentially optimise out the use of an auto variable completely, place it in machine registers, or other tricks to enhance performance of the code.   The compiler has less room to move with such optimisations when a static variable is involved.

In the end, however, the difference is probably insignificant - even in frequently called code.   Other things in your frequently called function - algorithms, etc - will probably have more of an effect on performance than worrying about whether a variable should be static or automatic.

I would suggest coding your function for readability and maintainability first.   That means, in practice, probably not making the variable static - because that means there are more defined paths for data to get in and out of your function, and therefore it is harder to understand.  Then test your code for performance in realistic use cases.   If some performance concern is identified, run it through a profiler, and work out where the real bottlenecks - if any - are.   More likely than not, the variable `a` in your code will not even be implicated in any bottlenecks.   Or, if it is, it be a low order effect - other factors will dominate.  Because, in the real world, the drivers of program performance are usually interactions between different sections of code, not something that can be affected by minor tweaks of properties of one variable.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.  Can I just say I'm sick of people calling me foolish (not you) for premature optimisation, and  saying it's the root of all evil.  I'm not a professional programmer, and I am not optimising anything, this is a hobby of mine and I want to know how the language works.  So far your answer appears to be the most realistic in that you've explained "it depends", and that it's much too complicated an issue to answer with a blanket statement.  So thanks, even though I haven't really got the answer I wanted.  I'll do my own testing with optimisation off.  Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think premature optimisation is the root of all evil, but it is highly inefficient use of your time and effort. You might spend days or weeks loving crafting some function, only to find that the optimisations you have done don't make any real difference to the program that uses your function.   That is why such things are called premature - if we were building a house, it would be akin to polishing one of the doorknobs on the laundry door and ignoring the need to make sure the walls can hold the roof up. Not being a professional does not make premature optimisation any more worthwhile.

Comment: I 100 per cent agree.  Except I'm not exactly optimising.  I'm only learning the language, I wanted to know what the effect of making something static was, and whether assigning every function call or declaring a variable every function call was faster.  And as you (as far as I know) rightly pointed out, it's a very hard question to answer.  I've got a lot to learn.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: So are you saying that for a function that goes something like: 

int someFunct(int arg)
{  
 int a = 2;
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {  
  a += arg + i;
 }  
 return a;
}  
  
And it's called frequently, the cpu won't create a or i each time it's called because it'll hold it in the register or something?

Damn it, can't you add new lines in the comments?  I'm sorry it's all mashed together.

Comment: Well .... the compiler has a bit of latitude.   Different compilers and different optimisation settings will give different results.  Unrolling of loops is a fairly basic optimisation.   Even a moderately aggressive compiler and optimisation setting might (in effect) simply replace the whole lot with "return 10*arg+47;" and be done with it.  Then the variables `a` and `i` would not even exist.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't seen that, yeah.  So let's just imagine a case of a function, which can't be optimised any simpler, like what you did, bottom line is you can't know whether a and i will be created and destroyed each time the function is called or whether it will hold those variables somewhere easily accessible, and therefore being faster than any static variable?

Comment: That's part of it. Your executing program is only required produce the same observable effects AS IF all the coded calculations had been performed. The compiler (and linker in some cases) can even eliminate your function entirely in some circumstances let alone variables in it.  Which can mean eliminating variables, static or not. That's why (except in some very specialised application areas) it is considered premature to focus on performance AT ALL before getting your code to produce intended results.  Code that quickly produces wrong results is not particularly useful.